# Error with Square Checkout API - "The order has expired"

Tags: square, square-connect, square-checkout

Getting this error (`category: INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR code: ORDER_EXPIRED`) from the `checkout` endpoint when a user clicks through, then comes back days later to pay. This is the endpoint that takes the order information and provides a unique checkout URL for the user.

**How long do orders have before they expire? I'm not even clear on what exactly is expiring?**

Not much sent over in the post. Trying to determine if I just need to alter the idempotency key "if an order has expired", which seems counterproductive.

```
$this->_order = ['redirect_url'              => $redirectUrl,
                 'idempotency_key'           => $this->_idempotencyKey,
                 'ask_for_shipping_address'  => false
        ];

$this->_order['order']['reference_id'] = (string) "{$this->getInvoice()->getId()}";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout urls expire in 24 hours. Square is working on updating the documentation to reflect this info.

Comment: Our solution was to make the idempotency key a hash of the unique invoice number and the date (as formatted string...`yyyymmdd`). Avoids the dead end when these things expire on us and sort of accomplished what is intended with the *idempotence*.